# Reading CAPTCHA using tesseract is giving wrong readings

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-tesseract

```
from urllib import urlopen,urlretrieve
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import subprocess
def cleanImage(imagePath):
    image=Image.open(imagePath)
    image=image.point(lambda x:0 if x<143 else 255)
    borederImage=ImageOps.expand(image,border=20,fill="white")
    borederImage.save(imagePath)
html=urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/humans-only")
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
imageLocation=soup.find('img',{'title':'Image CAPTCHA'})['src']
formBuildID=soup.find('input',{'name':'form_build_id'})['value']
captchaSID=soup.find('input',{'name':'captcha_sid'})['value']
captchaToken=soup.find('input',{'name':'captcha_token'})['value']
captchaURL="http://pythonscraping.com"+imageLocation
urlretrieve(captchaURL,"captcha.jpg")
cleanImage("captcha.jpg")
p=subprocess.Popen(['tesseract','captcha.jpg',"captcha"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
f=open('captcha.txt','r')
captchaResponce=f.read().replace(" ","").replace("\n","")
print "captcha responce attempt "+ captchaResponce+"\n\n"
try:
    print captchaResponce
    print len(captchaResponce)
    print type(captchaResponce)
except:
    print "No way"
```

Hello

This is my code for a testing site to download the CAPTCHA image(each time you open site you'll get a different CAPTCHA),then read it using tesseract in python.

I have tried to download the image directly and read it directly using tesseract it didn't get the correct CAPTCHA reading,so i added the function `cleanImage` to help but also it didn't read it correctly.

After searching online, my problem seems to be with tesseract not being "trained" to process the images correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.
**this code is from web-scraping book ,also this example purpose is to read the CAPTCHA &submit the form. This is in no way an attack or offensive tool to overload or harm the site.

Comment: First you should save the cleared image as file so you take a look at it. If it looks right you may also try tesseract from commandline to compare the results.

Comment: @MichaelButscher they give the same result

Comment: My apologies, I still firmly believe that defeating CAPCHA should not be taught.  It provokes the CAPCHA producers to come up with more and more convoluted schemes to ensure there is a human request.  This results in mere humans not being able to pass the human tests.

Comment: @Strom the only way for CAPTCHA producers to advance and make it only for humans is by learning how bots read it and tweaking it in such ways only humans brain pass it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used tesseract to solve captchas with nodejs. To get it running you need to do some image proccessing first (Depending on the captcha you try to solve).

[image]

If you take this type of captcha for example I did:

1. Remove "white noise"
2. Remove gray lines
3. Remove gray dots
4. Fill gaps
5. Change to grayscale image
6. NOW do OCR with tesseract

You can check out the code, how its done, and more docu here: https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver

Comment: if you checked my code ,i do image some mass image cleaning , i prefer a more technical answer if you can(contains more filtering **code**)

Answer (score 2):

`Tesseract` was trained to do more conventional OCR, and `CAPTCHA` is very challenging for it as is, because characters are not aligned, may have rotation, overlap and differ in size and fonts. You should try to invoke `tesseract` with different page segmentaion mode (`--psm` option). Here is a list of all possible values:

```
Page segmentation modes:
0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
7    Treat the image as a single text line.
8    Treat the image as a single word.
9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
10   Treat the image as a single character.
11   Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
12   Sparse text with OSD.
13   Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
     bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

Try modes with OSD (like 1, 7, 11, 12, 13). This will improve you recognition rate. But in order to really improve, you will have to write a program that finds separate letters (segments the image) and sends them to `tesseract` one by one (using `--psm 10`). `opencv` is a great library for image manipulation.  [This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) post may be a good start.

Regarding concerns about legitimacy of `CAPTCHA` recognition: it is ethical problem and lays beyond the scope of SO. `Pythonscraping` is a classic testing site and I see no problem whatsoever to assist solving the question. This concern is the same as teaching self-defense may be used to attack people.

Anyways, `CAPTCHA` is a very weak human-confirmation challenge and no site should be using it nowadays, while `reCAPTCHA` is much stronger, friendlier and free.

Comment: i think the problem is with** my tesseract** because it hasn't been trained ,i have seen some **training** going on with tesseract, people giving the real answer to tesseract and then let it try a bunch of time till it reaches correct answer, i am not sure how that is done but

Comment: When you install `tesseract` it is already "trained" to do standard text recognition. For example, if you  pass to it an image of regular text, it will recognize it with very few errors. The training you are talking about is domain specific adaptation, like handwritten connected text, fancy fonts, etc., and is not directly applicable in this case, because it demands **huge** amount of tagged data, that you do not have. If you want to try the machie learning approach, see  [this](https://blog.datawow.io/solving-text-based-captcha-with-machine-learning-part-1-628597b071fa) for start.

Comment: this makes sense ,can you add further image manipulation to make `tesseract` read the CAPTCHA (more correctly) ?

Comment: `tesseract` is doing a pretty good job in OCR and you do not want to dive into it's code and change; it is very complex project. It is much easier to detect and extract regions in CAPTCHA that contain separate characters and send them to `tesseract` one by one. In the process, you will **have to** manipulate the image, according to the kind of CAPTCHAs that you get. But there is no single **right** way to do it. So if you are looking for a simple solution, it does not exist. What will work perfectly on certain image, will not produce good results on other.